# Show $A^TP_{R(A)}=A^T$ for all $A$ in $\mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, projection, projection-matrices

Prove that right multiplication of the orthogonal projector that maps vectors to the range of $A$ by $A^T$ backs to $A^T$. Algebraically,

$$A^TP_{R(A)}=A^T$$

where $R(A)$ is the range of matrix $A$.

My try:

$$A^T(I-P_{R(A)})=0$$

Therefore, $I-P_{R(A)}$ is the projector onto $R(A)^{\perp}=N(A^T)$. I do not know how to argue the rest.

Comment: Aren’t you left-multiplying by $A^T$?

Comment: I think that this question requires additional precisions. First, if $A \in \mathbb R^{m \times n}$, it is not a linear operator as it doesn’t map a space into itself if $n \neq m$. Are you indeed supposing that $n$ can be different from $m$? Second, you speak of the projector $P_{R(A)}$. Do you mean the **orthogonal projector**? If yes it means that $\mathbb R^m$ is endowed with an inner product. Can you detail those points?

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net: You are absolutely right. I was wrong about the linear operator. Also, $P_{R(A)}$ is orthogonal projector onto range of $A$. I revised the statement. In addition, I am not sure why we need to say projection onto the range of $A$ is orthogonal or not because $I-P_{R(A)}$ is projector to the complementary subspace of $R(A)$ and need not be orthogonal projector. Could you elaborate that? Furthermore, the space is endowed with inner product.

Comment: The fact that $I-P_{R(A)}$ is the projector onto $R(A)^\perp$ is true because $P_{R(A)}$ is the orthogonal projector onto $R(A)$. This might not be true if the direction of the projection is different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any matrix $M$, $M=0$ if and only if $v^T M u=0$ for all column vectors $u$ and $v$ (of appropriate dimension).

For this question, let $u\in\mathbb{R}^m$ and $v\in\mathbb{R}^n$, then
$$v^TA^T(I-P_{R(A)})u=(Av)^T(I-P_{R(A)})u=0$$
since $Av\in R(A)$ and $(I-P_{R(A)})u\in R(A)^\bot$.

Comment: Please include your hint in the comment parts.

Comment: I have expanded this into a full answer.